# jQuery image slider issue in Chrome

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-chrome, safari

The below jQuery code is used on a PHP/Wordpress site. It works in FireFox, IE7+, and Opera but not in Chrome or Safari.

The code is an image slider and a popup image that should work in all browsers. But when I click the next/prev buttons, the popup image appears beside the image, not at the top.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var item_width = $('#slipers li').outerWidth(true); 
    var left_value = item_width * (-1); 

    $('#slipers li:first').before($('#slipers li:last'));
    $('#slipers ul').css({'left' : left_value});

    $('#prev').click(function() {
        var left_indent = parseInt($('#slipers ul').css('left')) + item_width;         
        $('#slipers ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 500,function(){             
            $('#slipers li:first').before($('#slipers li:last'));           
            $('#slipers ul').css({'left' : left_value});
        });         
        return false;   
    });

    $('#next').click(function() {
        var left_indent = parseInt($('#slipers ul').css('left')) - item_width;
        $('#slipers ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 500, function () {
            $('#slipers li:last').after($('#slipers li:first'));                    
            $('#slipers ul').css({'left' : left_value});
        }); 
        return false;
    });               
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.yah").mouseover(function() {

        $(".hover", this).addClass("mun");
    });
    $("li.yah").mouseleave(function() {

        $(".hover", this).removeClass("mun");
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP File:

```
<div id="bungkus">
        <div id="next"><img src="/images/kiri.png"></div>
    <div id="slipers"> 

        <ul class="bawah">
          /*looping when i get data from wp*/
            <li class="yah"><a href="#"  >
                 <img src ="img"> </a>

                <div class="hover hid"> 
                    <div class="judul1">                    
                        <img src="image"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="judul2"><?php the_title();?></div>
                        <div class="judul3"><?php excerpt(20);?></div>                   
                </div>
              </li>  
              /*looping end here */
                      </ul></div>
        <div id="prev" align="right"><img src="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/images/kanan.png"></div>


</div>
```

A demonstration of the issue can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hVVnC/7/). You will need to click many times (4 times) to see the error in Chrome.

Comment: If the problem regards only the z-index, you can tweak that on every interaction...create a fiddle so we can test your code

Comment: Just a front-end dev suggestion: 99% of sliders use a **left** arrow on the left, and a **right** arrow at the right side, and on click the sliders perform in just the opposite way you are doing it. So, looking forward to a better user experience I'd suggest you to take this in consideration.